# Handling a null-initialized object with the @ts-check option

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have enabled the quite useful `// @ts-check` option in VScode, but now I have no idea how to handle a null-initialized object.

Here is a simplified example:

```
// @ts-check

const settings = {
  a: null,
  b: null
}

settings.a = 10
```

VSCode reports **Type '10' is not assignable to type 'null'** in the last line,
I expected to be able to set `settings.a` later in the code.

Please note that this is Javascript, not Typescript. I've found many responses but all refer to TS and are not applicable to JS

Thank you.

Comment: what does it error from? javascript lsp doesn't give such error

Comment: As I wrote, VSCode editor with the @ts-check option enabled

Comment: @TachibanaShin [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&filetype=ts#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmUoEswHMIwLwwN4CgYYBDALhjAFcAbagGkJgCNyrb8BfffBJVDAHTFsMAIwAGANxA) - it errors quite expectedly because `a` is implicitly not given a type other than `null`.

Comment: the problem here is that he is not using typescript so the typescript LSP will not be run and if it does then the @ts-check will take effect

Comment: @TachibanaShin TS has had the ability to validate JS files since its inception: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html The `// @ts-check` directive is there to opt into type checking in a JS file: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro-to-js-ts.html#ts-check So, not what you describe as "the problem" is not it. See my answer for the actual solution - describing the types in JSDoc for TS to be able to use.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSDoc define your object in [`@typedef` (JSDoc)](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html) / [`@typedef` (TypeScript documentation)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#typedef-callback-and-param) and reference that within [`@type` (JSDoc)](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html) / [`@type` (TypeScript documentation)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#type). This assumes `b` is supposed to be a string for illustrative purposes:

```javascript
// @ts-check

/**
 * @typedef MyType 
 * @type {object}
 * @property {number|null} a - a numeric value 
 * @property {string|null} b - a string value
 */

/**
 * @type {MyType}
 */
const settings = {
  a: null,
  b: null
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=true&filetype=js#code/PTAEAEBcGcFoGMAWBTeBrAUB4AqHHQcJIBPAB2QBNkAzUAWRIBVzlQCipXQBvAewBGAK1SQAvhwhkATnwrTSvAHYBXALYDk0gD6qANnrGgAhqFgnQqtVoCW8UADdjelW0ngZcrYp7RI0myUAc10VAyMBMws-AODHZ1cOYCxcfEJibh5GFgoJQmT4PiU-UGhkSEhAoOhQAF5eAhMALkswvQAaRoEW-T0MCQwyiqroADpTeoBGAAYAblAFxYWQAHkAaUHyyuCxyPqAIhQDPn355eB1rCHt6vG60H2Adz5pPUpTxZAtWWkomKrLHxICZjo8qJthjs7vV-K4zksvtIflEBHw+HpkMYlIDgc49HwwZQITcxhNeGJ4UtQIjkeZBCJ4MClECQfjCcSRtDQColNQaIEqPMaS8ojy+QLKDjWQTwRyoXtQAAWABMlIRwG+IvMVk0v2ZuNB4OunIVsOQaupGqRWtAqPRmOx+ul7ON8vuPApVM+VtpoHpoileJlRNdtwVYtoEqFPptEf5SiogcNRLlt3sBw+VOFv3MnnkinsNhqTqD7KAA)

Note that you can directly define the the object in `@type`, however `@typedef` allows to

- reference it multiple times
- add documentation for the fields

With that said, defining the object shape in `@type` is much more compact:

```javascript
// @ts-check

/**
 * @type {{a: number|null; b: string|null}}
 */
const settings = {
  a: null,
  b: null
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=true&filetype=js#code/PTAEAEBcGcFoGMAWBTeBrAUB4AqHHQcJIBPAB2VAG8qBDALlADsBXAWwCNkAnAH1YA2AgNygOjaJG4BLJgHN+LIQF9lBHMAzwA9k0mhoySJFlzooALzUCoBsyUCANDfH2hGNRkPHT0AHS0lqAAjAAMoqCRUaAgAPIA0l5GJvL+HEEARChC2hkRMcAJWN4pZgGZAO7a3AIAJnlRIDzc1aCwBlKmzNqQtjkVyLVJPqnlVlIsyPmNwM2t7Rza2gLItEzdvbT9g8Ol-oFWVMrT0U3cLdxtoNocAFaovUw9fQLaA0MlvmOgLEy1yAAzWSDURnC5XX7-IFMQYbF5vHa7L7pKwAFgATCcZnNLu1WJweHCtq93kjRijQBMptFImD5mIlis1kTth9ksigkcsbTZud6Td7vBHs9iQi2SMyhTIYDgbVQbzwe1pdDYU9NqziuzRvBMg0aXTcaAyC0KNxSKAddJzGr4aSgA)